# pros and cons of data-binding for GUI form design

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I know that data-binding sometimes can save lots of effort, but I'm not very clear on how to make decision that to use or not to use data-binding in various contexts.

Comment: I tagged swing, assuming you mean desktop GUI

Answer (score 1):

If the project gets more than 1000 lines, you will end up creating some data-binding solution yourself, even if you don't realize it. But it will be messier and changes will be hard to introduce.

So, using a data-binding framework is advisable. The choice of which framework to use now becomes hard. [JGoodies Data Binding](https://binding.dev.java.net/),  [BeansBinding](https://beansbinding.dev.java.net/), [BeanProperties](https://bean-properties.dev.java.net/)

Comment: Thanks, can you help answer another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666311/if-use-databinding-in-a-dialog-how-to-restore-data-when-user-cancelled-the-editi